# LDAP JS with Node JS Finding users passing in patterns of string

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, ldap, ldap-query

I am currently using LDAP JS for Authentication in Angular JS app and everything works perfectly fine.

I am now building a new view and the requirement I have is this:

- I have text box in which admin will write may be a few letters of a user id present in LDAP.
- I want to show app matching ID present in LDAP on a typeahead/suggestions. I know how typeahead works so that's not an issue. The issue is how can I pass a rejex or pattern matching kind of a thing for `uid` in `search()` method.

My sample code is here:

```
function GetAllLDAPUser(dnFilter, res) {

    client.search('uid=**WHAT-PATTERN-CAN-I-PASS-HERE**' + dnFilter, opts, function(err, result) {

            result.on('searchEntry', function(entry) {

                // I usually read entry.object or entry.raw here , that works

            });
            result.on('end', function(result) {

                .......
            });
        }
    }
}
```

So the question is what should I pass in place of 
`WHAT-PATTERN-CAN-I-PASS-HERE`

Results :
Suppose I type `an`. The typeahead will show all user id starting with `an` like `ana`, `anamon`, `analisa` etc.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have written the final solution and closed [the issue on the project's repository](https://github.com/mcavage/node-ldapjs/issues/259)

> For pattern matching, we need to play with the 'filter' field in option object which we pass to the search method. So I ended up doing something like below:

```
var dnFilter = 'ou=People,o=Intra,dc=YOURCOMPANY,dc=com'; //depends on your LDAP settings.
var query;
var matchedUsers = [];
query.LDAPName = "dummy"; //some name which resides in LDAP 
//You can even have one simple variable rather than having this query object.
opts = {
    scope: 'sub',
    filter: (shcDisplayName = '+ query.LDAPName + ')
    '
};

//Do not use 'shcDisplayName' , this will be any variable stored in your LDAP object. You need get 
//the structure of LDAP end point you are working on. For me, I had one variable 'shcDisplayName'
//on which I wanted to play so I am using this variable in my filter.
client.search(dnFilter, opts, function(err, result) {

        result.on('searchEntry', function(entry) {
                matchedUsers.push({
                    'Name': entry.object.shcDisplayName,
                    'Id': entry.object.uid
                });
            }

            result.on('end', function(result) {

                    if (matchedUsers.length) { //if any match was found.

                        //send the json result back
                        res.json(matchedUsers);

                        //if you want to send json back, do not use res.send() otherwise you will end up getting
                        //circular reference error. 
                    }
                }

                result.on('error', function(ex) {
                    //Handle errors here if any
                });

            });
    }
}
```